# Can You store a Django model in an ElasticSearch index?

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-models

Can I store a Django model in an ElasticSearch index?

If yes, then how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The question is really generic question and I don't know you checked the following pages or not. Here are some resources for you to check how you can do it :

- [Github] Django Elasticsearch DSL is a package that allows indexing of django models in elasticsearch. https://github.com/django-es/django-elasticsearch-dsl
- [Article] How to Use ElasticSearch With Django - https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-use-elasticsearch-with-django-ff49fe02b58d
- [Article] How to use Elasticsearch with Django https://sunscrapers.com/blog/how-to-use-elasticsearch-with-django/